# Can't install Shopify/CLI on Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: npm, installation, command-line-interface, shopify

Can't install Shopify/CLI on Linux Ubuntu 22.04

Here is the command to install it:

```
npm init @shopify/app@latest -- --template node
```

Here is the error:

```
file:///home/mycomputername/.npm/_npx/f27a05a5c3c9c53d/node_modules/@shopify/cli- 
kit/dist/index-eb280c22.js:14374
        output += colorJson(stringifyMessage(enumToken.value) ?? {});
                                                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:133:18)
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/mycomputername/Desktop/newshopifyapp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c create-app "--template" "node"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/mycomputername/.npm/_logs/2022-06-22T15_18_41_596Z-debug-0.log
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Fernando

Comment: Try upgrade your nodejs version

Comment: Javascript tooling is so awesome. Nothing has changed since 2012, still the same old problems. Yay, go little Javascript go.

Comment: Thank you @FabioFilippi. That did the trick. I'm using Linux and for some reason when installing nodejs, the version 12 was in. Now with the update it's all good. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updating NodeJs did the trick thanks to @FabioFillipi.

Comment: updating node helped me too